# C++ - The procedure entry point could not be located?

Tags: c++, dll, entry-point

I am on Windows 8 using Visual Studio 2012. I am using gtkmm in C++ and I'm trying to display a gui. When I first start my program, without my program even reaching the main method, I get an error dialog box saying "The procedure entry point ?_Init@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ could not be located in RemoteController.exe", which is the name of my application. The first thing I noted after trying to find a solution to this error is the fact that it's calling my executable a dll. No one else with this error that I've seen seem to have it doing that. I really don't understand what's happening because it just randomly started doing this for no reason. The steps I've done to try to fix the problem are:
1. Switch between the C++ main and the Windows main method. (I made sure to change subsystem setting appropriately with that).
2. Make a new project and paste my code into it.

I really don't know what's wrong with it. My best guess is it must have something to do with gtkmm, but it was working and then just randomly stopped working, without me changing code.

Comment: It is a private member of the std::locale class implementation.  How you ended up with an external dependency on it is very hard to guess.

Comment: Do you have any ideas what I might be doing to cause it?

Comment: Try giving the .exe a different name - something seems to be trying to load an export from a module named "remotecontroller".  Also, Loading the program in depends.exe (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Ok, I used Dependency Walker and at the bottom it says at least one module has an unresolved import due to missing export function. How can I tell which one that is? And how would I even fix that?

Comment: You should see a module with a "module warning" icon (see http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/hidr_module_tree_view.htm). If you select that module in the 'Module dependency Tree View' it should show an error in the imports list about the function that's missing (which will probably be the `locale::_Init()` function you see in the error message).  The tree view should make it clear what module is trying to import the function. `locale::Init()` should be in the C++ runtime - is your program linking to the DLL runtime or the static runtime?  Debug or release?